# getting undefined error in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to list all categories in my XML file and link them with a javascript function which opens an xsl file.

I'keep getting this error: Novel is Undefined. where Novel is a category from the XML

Here is my code.

```
var root=myxmldoc.getElementsByTagName("CATEGORY");
        for (i=0;i<root.length;++i) {
            var catName=(root[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            txt='<a href="#" onClick="javascript:Navigate('+catName+')">'+catName+'</a>';
            document.getElementById("left-sidebar").innerHTML+=txt; 

        }
```

In the code above, Navigate(var) is a function that loads various .XSL files for each category.

Please can anyone help me understand why the error keeps coming up?

Thanks

Comment: Does the error happen when the code above is executed, or when the link is clicked?

Comment: off topic, but you'd get better performance if you built txt as a string and did the `innerHTML` update just once, outside the loop.

Comment: can you provide the XML in this example?

Comment: @David Grayson - the error happened when the link is clicked
@Spudley - i will try that, thank you for the tip :)
@pixelbobby - I've been helped with the problem. But if you still want to see it, i will be glad to post it. Thank you

Comment: @Spudley, i can't seem to do what you suggested. could you help me out please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you generate the link, it'll come up as:

```
 <a href="#" onClick="javascript:Navigate(Novel)">Novel</a>
```

Note the lack of quotes around `Novel`, meaning Javascript will see that as a variable, which happens to not be defined.

You neeed to embed quotes in your string generation like this:

```
 txt='<a href="#" onClick="javascript:Navigate(\''+catName+'\')">'+catName+'</a>';
                                               ^^ here      ^^ and here
```

so that the HTML will look like:

```
 <a href="#" onClick="javascript:Navigate('Novel')">Novel</a>
```

Comment: Oh okay i get it, thank you very much and it works. is there a reason why its written like [\''+catName+'\'] and not like ['\'+catName+'\']?

Comment: Because you need the escaped quote WITHIN your string. If it's outside, then it's just some random used-to-be-a-quote-but-isn't-anymore dangling around and breaking the syntax.